# S3 files being processed multiple times in AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a Java Lambda function that is triggered by S3 Event every 15 minutes.  I've noticed that over the period of about every 3 hours, each Lambda call includes the latest file that was uploaded AND all of the files that were uploaded before it within that 3 hour timespan.

So, if the  when iterating through the entire List, it repeats the files that had already been processed in an earlier Lambda call.

How do I get it to only process the most recent file uploaded?  In node.js, there is a context.suceed(), which I assume marks that event as successfully processed.  Java doesn't seem to have that.

Below are the Cloudwatch logs.

```
08:35:16 START RequestId: 56c0dc17-6f77-11e6-a102-7517541f4ac3 Version: $LATEST
08:35:26 TIME - AUTHENTICATE: 8101ms
08:35:26 TIME - MESSAGE PARSE: 1ms
08:35:26 data :: event/events/2016/    08/31/2016    0831123000.export.csv
08:35:35 Processed 147 events
08:35:35 TIME - FILE PARSE: 9698
08:35:35 Found 1 event files
08:35:35 Total function took: 17800ms
08:35:35 END RequestId: 56c0dc17-6f77-11e6-a102-7517541f4ac3
08:35:35 REPORT RequestId: 56c0dc17-6f77-11e6-a102-7517541f4ac3 Duration: 19403.67 ms Billed Duration: 19500 ms Memory Size: 192 MB Max Memory Used: 116 MB
08:45:03 START RequestId: bcb8e064-6f78-11e6-baea-a312004d2418 Version: $LATEST
08:45:03 TIME - AUTHENTICATE: 119ms
08:45:03 TIME - MESSAGE PARSE: 0ms
08:45:03 data :: event/events/2016/    08/31/2016    0831123000.export.csv
08:45:05 Processed 147 events
08:45:05 data :: event/events/2016/    08/31/2016    0831124500.export.csv
08:45:06 Processed 211 events
08:45:06 TIME - FILE PARSE: 2499
08:45:06 Found 2 event files
08:45:06 Total function took: 2618ms
08:45:06 END RequestId: bcb8e064-6f78-11e6-baea-a312004d2418
08:45:06 REPORT RequestId: bcb8e064-6f78-11e6-baea-a312004d2418 Duration: 2796.25 ms Billed Duration: 2800 ms Memory Size: 192 MB Max Memory Used: 116 MB
09:05:02 START RequestId: 8747aa    08-6f7b-11e6-80fd-f30a15cf07fc Version: $LATEST
09:05:02 TIME - AUTHENTICATE: 98ms
09:05:02 TIME - MESSAGE PARSE: 0ms
09:05:02 data :: event/events/2016/    08/31/2016    0831123000.export.csv
09:05:03 Processed 147 events
09:05:03 data :: event/events/2016/    08/31/2016    0831124500.export.csv
09:05:04 Processed 211 events
09:05:04 data :: event/events/2016/    08/31/2016    0831130000.export.csv
09:05:04 Processed 204 events
09:05:04 TIME - FILE PARSE: 2242
09:05:04 Found 3 event files
09:05:04 Total function took: 2340ms
09:05:04 END RequestId: 8747aa    08-6f7b-11e6-80fd-f30a15cf07fc
```

**EDIT 1** I believe the question has been answered by Michael, however below is some of the code for anyone else.  I am indeed using a global List to hold the records.

public class LambdaHandler {

```
private final List<GDELTEventFile> eventFiles = new ArrayList<>();
private AmazonS3Client s3Client;
private final CSVFormat CSV_FORMAT = CSVFormat.TDF.withIgnoreEmptyLines().withTrim();

public void gdeltHandler(S3Event event, Context context) {
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    long time = 0L;

    sw.start();
    s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider());
    sw.split();
    System.out.println("TIME - AUTHENTICATE: " + sw.getSplitTime() + "ms");
    time += sw.getSplitTime();
    sw.reset();

    sw.start();
    processEvent(event);
    sw.split();
    System.out.println("TIME - MESSAGE PARSE: " + sw.getSplitTime() + "ms");
    time += sw.getSplitTime();
    sw.reset();

    sw.start();
    processFiles();
    sw.split();
    System.out.println("TIME - FILE PARSE: " + sw.getSplitTime());
    time += sw.getSplitTime();

    System.out.println("Found " + eventFiles.size() + " event files");
    System.out.println("Total function took: " + time + "ms");
}

private void processEvent(S3Event event) {
    List<S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord> records = event.getRecords();
    for (S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord record : records) {
        long filesize = record.getS3().getObject().getSizeAsLong();
        eventFiles.add(new GDELTEventFile(record.getS3().getBucket().getName(), record.getS3().getObject().getKey(), filesize));
    }
}

private void processFiles() {
    for (GDELTEventFile event : eventFiles) {
        try {
            System.out.println(event.getBucket() + " :: " + event.getFilename());
            GetObjectRequest request = new GetObjectRequest(event.getBucket(), event.getFilename());
            S3Object file = s3Client.getObject(request);
            try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file.getObjectContent()))) {
                CSVParser parser = new CSVParser(reader, CSV_FORMAT);
                int count = 0;
                for (CSVRecord record : parser) {
                        count++;
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("Processed " + count + " events");
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println("IOException :: " + ioe);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the information in the `data ::` lines coming from?  I have never seen S3 send more than one record per event... in fact, my code is designed to stop and throw an exception if it ever does, because that's unexpected.  I suspect that you may have failed to account for possible container reuse.  If the Lambda event reuses the same container from the previous invocation, it is possible you have a global data structure that's holding on to the old events?

Comment: Hi Michael, If you're asking where the actual line is being printed, 'm printing those lines from within the function.  It's just a System.out.println.  The file itself is generated by the gdelt service every 15 minutes and I download it on an ec2 instance and then upload it via cli.  How do i account for container reuse in lambda?  Never heard of that before...

Comment: When I say "account for" container reuse, I mean [be aware that it's a thing](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) and code accordingly. Each time a function fires, it fires into an idle process running your Lambda function... but it may be new or may be the *same* process that ran the function last time, or some time before that, being reused (as long as you haven't uploaded new code).  If you're pushing records from S3 onto a global array, not one scoped to your handler (for example) then when you iterate that array, it's going to *sometimes* contain old events.

Comment: Oh, and I was asking for the origin of the data, rather than the origin of the output.  A little bit of your code -- just the part from the beginning, up to and including where that message prints out -- will probably illustrate the problem.

Comment: Looks like you might be right, I am using a global List.  I knew Lambda would hold open the container, but never occurred to me that it would hold the actual process open.  I will refactor to use locally scoped variables.

Comment: There's only one process per container, and only one invocation will be runnning on each process at a time.  When the invocation finishes, the process is frozen.  It will eventually be destroyed, but if a low-traffic function invoked again within a few minutes, there's a reasonable chance of container/process reuse by "thawing" the frozen process for faster startup... so, on the topic, don't forget to clean up your temp files, because they will also persist and take up space as long as the container hangs around.

Comment: Well, it runs every 15 minutes (that's how often the csv file is generated).  By temp files, I assume you mean if I am explicitly writing out to any files?  If I'm not, are there any temp files generated by the VM that I need to clean up somehow?  I've redeployed and am letting it process a few of the csv files to see what happens.

Comment: Looks like your answer was spot-on, though for some reason it's taking longer now than it did before.  At least before, the initial execution would take about 15 - 20 seconds, but then subsequent executions would take only a few seconds.  It's now demonstrating further that perhaps this is not the most appropriate use-case for Lambda....At any rate, please put up a quick answer so I can accept it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a case of code that overlooks an important aspect of Lambda's [container reuse](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) -- container reuse in Lambda includes process reuse.  When a function is executed in a reused container, it's also necessarily running in the same process that was used before as well.

S3's event notification data structure is such that it can include more than one object per event, but i practice, this never happpens... but pushing the event data into a global structure means that if the container is reused, then later function invocations will see the old data.

While this can be very useful as a cache, it has significant implications for how code must be designed -- always expect but never assume that your process may survive from one invocation to a future, subsequent invocation, and code accordingly.

Note that container reuse also means you need to clean up any temp files, if there is a chance that many reuses of a container will result in space exhaustion there.

Note also that redeploying your function code always means that old containers will be abandoned, not reused for future invocations of the latest version.