# amazon aws lambda function variable carryover

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am using an python AWS lambda function to monitor ec2 instances.  While using it I noticed that when I ran the function it would occasionally save the value of a list.  For example:

```
`newVar = "test"
newList = []
newList.append(newVar)
print newList`
```

The first time through it prints:

```
`[test]`
```

The second time it prints:

```
`[test, test]`
```

I was wondering if anyone else has had this issue and how they solved it?

Comment: Did you close your initial session ? try: `del newList[:]`

Comment: whenever a lambda function fails to do a task in 5 mins or within timeout period, it retries 3 times.Is your test failing for some reason?and then lambda is retrying?

Comment: My test isn't failing.  It runs how it's supposed to.

Comment: @dsgdfg That worked. Thank you

Comment: This is caused by [container reuse, which causes the same issue for all languages](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39292199/1695906).  Always write code that assumes the container *might* be reused.